# Load UITabbarcontroller from a UIViewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to develop a tab bar controller application with four UIViewControllers. I have already programed my app. Now I need to add Login in my App. I have added a separate  UIViewcontroller for login (Which is not part of TabbarController). Login is working fine. How can I load UITabbarcontroller after login is success.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this is to create a UINavigationController to house the login view and when a login is complete you push the UITabViewController onto the Navigation Controller. It works well and you can just hide the navigation bar so the user doesn't just jump back to login(unless you want this).

You could also just swap out the rootviewcontroller of the window but I like the navigation controller solution better and you can easily popToRootViewController to go back to login when you want.

Comment: Rooster, thanks for quick response. I'm a new. How can I complete push the UITabViewController onto the Navigation Controller. Can you give me an example.

Comment: That's kind of a bigger answer without knowing the details of how you set up your project. Are you using a storyboard or just .xib's? You would have to set up your project as a navigation based project first.

Comment: I'm using storyboard. After followed your instruction I'm able to navigate to my UITabbarViewController.        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
        DialpadViewController *lvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dialPad"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:lvc animated:YES]; How ho hide navigation bar?

Comment: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; in your viewDidLoad for your login viewController